# Skip query if NOT optional variable is undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo-client

I have to run a query that has as mandatory variable which is the result of another query.
Since such result can be `number | undefined`, typescript complains saying that my variable can only be a `number` but **not** `undefined`

```
const { data: firstQueryData } = useQuery(GET_MY_FIRST_QUERY_DATA, {
    variables: {
      firstVariable: 100
    }
  })

const myVariable = myQueryData?.getMyQueryData <-- This is "number" | "undefined"

const { data: secondQueryData } = useQuery(GET_MY_SECOND_QUERY_DATA, {
  variables: {
    secondVariable: myVariable <-- This is "number" | "undefined" while it should only be "number"
  }
})
```

I tried to use **skip** but TS still complains:

```
const { data: mySecondQuery } = useQuery(GET_MY_SECOND_QUERY_DATA, {
  variables: {
    secondVariable: myVariable
  },
  skip: !myVariable
})
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue and solved it by checking the truthiness of the variable first, eg:

```
const { data: mySecondQuery } = useQuery(GET_MY_SECOND_QUERY_DATA,
  myVariable
    ? {
        variables: {
          secondVariable: myVariable,
        },
      }
    : { skip: true }
);
```

Hope that helps!